# I've been trying to include AES encryption into a simple socket.io program in javascript, but I'm running into errors

Tags: javascript, encryption, socket.io, cryptography, aes

> I've been trying to include AES encryption into a simple socket.io
> program in javascript, but I'm running into errors (I assume it's
> regarding the crypto-js CDN file). How do I correct it? Also, is there
> any other alternative to implementing AES encryption in such a
> program?

**//client.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Socket.io Client</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-3.1.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <input type="text" id="message" name="message"><br><br>
            <button type="button" onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
        </form>
        <script>
            const socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

            function sendMessage() {
                const key = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(32); // generate a 32-bit random key

                const message = document.getElementById('message').value;
                console.log(`Original message: ${message}`);

                const cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key).toString();
                console.log(`Encrypted message: ${cipher}`);

                socket.emit('encrypted-message', { message: cipher });
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**//server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const crypto = require('crypto');

let key; // define a global variable for the key

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Client connected');

  socket.on('encrypted-message', ({ message, encryptionKey }) => {
    console.log(`Encrypted message received: ${message}`);

    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16); // generate a random initialization vector

    // use the key passed from the client
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', encryptionKey, iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(message, 'base64', 'utf8');
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');

    console.log(`Decrypted message: ${decrypted}`);
  });

  // when the client connects, send the key to the client
  key = crypto.randomBytes(32);
  socket.emit('key', { key });
});

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 8080');
});
```

Comment: Have a look at [Block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) especially section *Cipher block chaining (CBC)* with regard to meaning and purpose of an IV. The CrytoJS code lacks the IV at all, and the NodeJS code does not use the IV from encryption.

Comment: The snippets won't run, and the error is not described.